# Python:List:Out of Range cases

Tags: python, list

imagine that i have a list like `l=[[10,50,90],[70,80,90],[88,90,55]]`

```
10 50 90  
70 80 40  
88 90 55
```

I sum an item with the others around it(so the sum of 9 items).

but if I choose to sum an item on the border, the index will be out of range.

is it possible to when the index is out of range, instead of bugging,to add a particular number(like 1) for each missing items (out of range index).

I just don't know how to handle the error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that returns 0 when the indexes are out-of-bounds, and otherwise the value from the grid. Then sum up the results from calling the function with each position.

Comment: I've used your method and it works pretty well, thx you and everybody else.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use try-catch style error handling (http://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions has some info) or write your code with if blocks like

```
if (index == 0) then
    handleEdgeCase(index)
else
    handleGeneralCase(index)
```

to notice the unusual situations and deal with them.

Answer (score 1):

Slicing is the key to this one. It can gracefully handle the edges. The tricky part is choosing the correct slice range.

```
l=[[10,50,90],[70,80,90],[88,90,55]]
```

Logic is:

```
rows = l[row_idx-1:row_idx+2]
cols = row[col_idx-1:col_idx+2] for row in rows
```

The first part of the slice can't be negative so we have to lower bound at 0.  The second part can extend beyond the end.

```
xleft = x-1 if x>0 else x
l[xleft:x+2]
```

It needs to be flattened into a list, I have chosen to create a generator using the double for loop over the slices of slices.

```
def neighbours(iterable, x, y):
    xleft = x-1 if x>0 else x
    yleft = y-1 if y>0 else y
    return ( i for row in l[xleft:x+2] for i in row[yleft:y+2] )
```

Just to show some work, please don't judge the if else slice args. ;)

```
>>>x,y = 0,0
>>>print list( i for row in l[x-1 if x>0 else x:x+2] for i in row[y-1 if y>0 else y:y+2] )
[10, 50, 70, 80]
>>>print sum( i for row in l[x-1 if x>0 else x:x+2] for i in row[y-1 if y>0 else y:y+2] )
210

>>>x,y = 1,1
>>>print list(neighbours(l, x, y))
[10, 50, 90, 70, 80, 90, 88, 90, 55]
>>>print sum(neighbours(l, x, y))
623    

>>>x,y = 2,2
>>>print list(neighbours(l, x, y))
[80, 90, 90, 55]
>>>print sum(neighbours(l, x, y))
315
```